# Unable to host Umbraco CMS at Plesk Web Hosting. Getting System.Security.SecurityException: Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco8, plesk-onyx

I am trying to host Umbraco CMS on Plesk Web Hosting but getting **Security Exception**, I also tried to change the **CAS trust level to FULL** but no success, see the full error below:

```
Security Exception
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SecurityException: Request failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +96
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +80
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Object assemblyOrString, SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +288
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(CompressedStack cs, PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, RuntimeAssembly asm, SecurityAction action) +70
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +40
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +30
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_IsCodeDomProviderTypeValid() +10
   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetRecompilationHash(CompilationSection ps) +2399
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.get_RecompilationHash() +92
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDateInternal(Int64 cachedHash) +502
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(Int64 cachedHash) +53
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +133
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +695
```

Further, I modify the Web.config file and added `<trust level="Full" />`, see code below:-

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
...
...
<trust level="Full" />
</system.web>
```

After modifying the Web.config file I am getting **Configuration Error**, see the full error below

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file.

Source Error:

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
```

I also change the required File and folder permissions guided by the Umbraco CMS 
[Umbraco CMS Setup Guide-> File and folder permissions](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/getting-started/setup/server-setup/permissions)

**Please help me with how I can host Umbraco ASP.NET CMS on Plesk Web Hosting Environment.**

**Server Details:**

Hosting Provider: Plesk

.Net framework version I am using 4.7.03062

Answer (score 0):

Which hosting are you using? You need to contact your hosting provider to give full permission for you. If your hosting provider doesn't support Full Trust, although on your code, you use Full Trust, it won't work